# Запись файла до остановки скрипта Python

Tags: python, sql, csv

Есть часть кода, которая вызывается из главного скрипта:

```
file_name = f"{date_1}.csv"
with open(file_name, 'a', newline='') as file:
         writer = csv.writer(file)
         for complex_sla_event in SLA_event:
             for complex_ticket_event in ticket_event:
                 if complex_sla_event[0] == complex_ticket_event[3]:
                     if complex_ticket_event[2] - timedelta(hours=36) <= complex_sla_event[2].replace(tzinfo=None) <= \     
                         complex_ticket_event[2] + timedelta(hours=36):     
                       result = complex_sla_event + complex_ticket_event
                       writer.writerow(result)
```

Данный цикл должен записывать агрегацию из двух sql запросов в файл .csv
Далее бот будет отправлять сформированный файл в чат
Проблема в том, что файл формируется только после остановки скрипта, а мне необходимо что бы скрипт работал постоянно

upd
Вопрос решен, попробовал сделать запись в папку на локальный диск - файл создался сразу, не появлялся именно в Pycharm колонке. Я потратил часов 8 своей жизни для того что бы это понять

Comment: @Глеб поправил, прошу прощения, не опытный)

Comment: Ничего, со всеми бывает.